# Convert byte[] to bitmap in C# result weird

Tags: c#, arrays, bitmap

I am trying to convert 3 byte[12x12] to bitmap (36x12) but the result (the red rectangle section in the image) is not matching (top) :...

[image: I am supposed to get the red section as a result, but my result (on top) is not matching]

here is the code I did :

```
Width = 36;
Height = 12;

private Bitmap setpixel(byte[] bits)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
    for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
        {
            int index = (y * Width + x) * 3;
            Color color = Color.FromArgb(bits[index + 2], bits[index + 1], bits[index]);
            bmp.SetPixel(x, y, color);
        }
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

The byte[] input is a combination of 3 byte[12x12x3] :

What I use to combine byte[] :

```
List < int> list = new List<int>(){}; 

list.AddRange(Arr001); 
list.AddRange(Arr002); 
list.AddRange(Arr003); 

ResultArray = list.ToArray();
```

Edit : I understand that the problem come from the byte[] input.
I need to create 1 byte[36x12x3] from 3 byte[12x12x3], any ideas how can i achieve this ?

Comment: At first glance, I don't see anything too obvious. Are you sure that your input byte[] is what you expect it to be?

Comment: The Width of the large image (bits array) is not 36.

Comment: Looking at it again: Is it possible that x and y are flipped? Meaning: You think you are reading rows but actually you are reading columns?

Comment: I would be fairly sure that there is a mistake regarding the input values. Maybe the pixelFormat is incorrect? The width or height? Maybe the `bits` have a stride that does not equal width*3? I don't think there is any way to tell without also seeing the code that created the  byte array.

Comment: The byte[] input is a combination of 3 byte[12*12*3]. 
When I use this script for 1 byte[12*12*3] i correctly get the 12*12 image, but when i combine the 3 byte[] into 1 it got this bad result.

What i use to combine byte[] :

List < int> list = new List<int>(){};
  
  list.AddRange(Arr001);
  list.AddRange(Arr002);
  list.AddRange(Arr003);
  
  ResultArray = list.ToArray();

Comment: Can you add that info to the question by [edit]ing it, please? And I think that's where it derails, actually. If you have 12x12 pieces on the in-side, you need to handle the byte[] in 12x12 pieces, too.

Comment: Ok @Fildor i think i get it. How can i add lines by lines my others arrays to the first one ?

Comment: The updated example is still incomplete without showing how you get the individual arrays. If the goal is to copy a region from a source image to a new image you should just write a loop copies the pixels directly. Using unsafe and Buffer.BlockCopy if you want performance.

Comment: Why do you use list<int> and not list<byte> if you use bytes as data in your arrays?

Comment: I see your problem. You are appending the arrays but not accounting for the fact that you are changing the width of the bitmap. E.g. in your 12x12 input array at index 12 the data goes to the next scanline, but for the output at offset 12 it should still be on the first scanline because the width is now 36. Your bytes are out of sequence, hence the duplication. It's not as simple as just appending the input arrays. I'll see if I can put an example together of how I would do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I would do. A big change is how I get the bitmap data but that has nothing to do with your problem, it's just a better way. SetPixel() is extremely slow by comparison, but you could go back to that if you wanted.

Your issue lies in the fact that you stacked the input with AddRange(), you're not accounting for the bitmap scanlines of the output. I stacked the bytes the same way that you did and then the key is computing the "srcOffset" in that "ResultArray". The way I did it was use the j height iterator of the 36x12 output, adding the index of which input array you are on multiplied by the input array size, finally adding by the remainder of that same division to get the offset in the scanline of the 12x12 input. I ran it and it seems to come out correctly.

This is a visual example of what happens to the first scanline given the stacked input:
[image]

```
var inputWidth = 12;
var inputHeight = 12;
var inputBytesPerPixel = 3;

var Arr001 = new byte[inputWidth * inputHeight * inputBytesPerPixel];
var Arr002 = new byte[inputWidth * inputHeight * inputBytesPerPixel];
var Arr003 = new byte[inputWidth * inputHeight * inputBytesPerPixel];

var list = new List<byte>();

list.AddRange(Arr001);
list.AddRange(Arr002);
list.AddRange(Arr003);

var ResultArray = list.ToArray();

var outputWidth = 36;
var outputHeight = 12;

var bitmap = new Bitmap(outputWidth, outputHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);
var bitmapBytes = new byte[bitmapData.Stride * bitmap.Height];
var bitmapBytesPerPixel = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(bitmap.PixelFormat) / 8;

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0, bitmapBytes, 0, bitmapBytes.Length);

for (int j = 0; j < bitmapData.Height; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < bitmapData.Width; i++)
    {
        var destOffset = j * bitmapData.Stride + i * bitmapBytesPerPixel;
        var srcOffset = (j * inputWidth + i / inputWidth * inputWidth * inputHeight + i % inputWidth) * inputBytesPerPixel;

        bitmapBytes[destOffset] = ResultArray[srcOffset];
        bitmapBytes[destOffset + 1] = ResultArray[srcOffset + 1];
        bitmapBytes[destOffset + 2] = ResultArray[srcOffset + 2];
    }
}

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bitmapBytes, 0, bitmapData.Scan0, bitmapBytes.Length);

bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
```

Comment: if i go more than 1024 in outputWidth, it seem ignoring some values.. any solution ?

Comment: after 1024, it repeat first values...

Comment: Obviously my example only works under certain scenarios. One being the input and output heights must be the same, and another being the output width must be a multiple of the input width. 1024 is not a multiple of 12. These constraints can be easily overcome, but will need more work. Spend some time on it and if you are stumped I'll try to assist.

Comment: @RibasSamuel You should look deeper into how images are stored in memory. You're clearly not grasping the entire situation if you're having issues with this.

Comment: @Rich small nitpick: this kind of code is _so_ much more readable if you just call your variables for iterating over the width and height `x` and `y` rather than `i` and `j` ;)

Comment: @Nyerguds This is just the convention I use, picked up from many other devs. Since `i` is commonly used as an iterator and with vectors i is the x direction, j is the y direction, and k is the z direction, it makes sense for anyone familiar with vectors.